# What if 2 devs push their own code on master branch?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Im new with git and I have a question and can't find any answer on internet.
So basically, 2 developers are working on the same project and share their code on a remote GitHub repository. The first dev has pushed his code on the remote repo. What happens if just after the second dev push his own code too to the repository ? Any conflict ? It will erase the first one modifications ? Will it merge ?

Comment: If there is no conflict, the two branches will be merged without issue and both sets of changes will be applied. If there is a conflict, the second developer will have to resolve the conflict (as another commit) then merge.

Comment: Git doesn't care who pushed the work, or on what branch. A merge is a merge.

Comment: @CoryKramer that's incorrect. The second push will be rejected even if there is no conflict, because the second dev's branch would be behind the remote master branch. The merge or rebase would need to be made locally.

Comment: EDIT : Both are working on master branch

Comment: @KheopsHD the easier way for you to clearly see what would happen is to just do it. Create a github project. Clone itin directory user1. Clone it again in directory user2. Create a commit in user1 and push it. Do the same in user2. See what happens.

Comment: All you need is pull, pull, pull is all you need

Answer (score 1):

By default, if there are conflicts the push will get rejected. The other developer will need to pull the new code and solve any merge conflicts before being able to merge successfully. This is why working on branches is important. Each developer works on a separate branch, on hopefully separate parts of the code, so when they're done they make sure there aren't any merge conflicts with their code, if there are they should resolve them, then merge it into the main branch.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether each developer is on a different branch. Branches are just commit pointers, and the merge isn't concerned with branches.

Comment: The push will be rejected even if there is no conflict.

Comment: All that requires is a pull, which results in a fast-forward merge. It's not a definitive reason to work on different branches.

Answer (score 1):

The second dev will *not* be able to push their code to the remote repo.
Their `git push` will fail with an error message stating that the remote is ahead of the their local copy.

They'll have to do a `git pull` first, resolve conflicts if any, and then do another `git push`